# Is that correct to say?

Tags: grammar, syntactic-analysis

Speaking about bedtime reading... Please, help me with my grammar

> "As a rule, I don't take handsome dead conductors to bed, but if it is Bernstein, my husband doesn't mind".

Comment: It's correct.  Maybe not politically or socially correct...

Comment: @Cord Thank you for your response! But I don't completely understand why it's not Politically correct.. It is just a humor.

Comment: @Natalia That was me trying to be humorous/sarcastic.  I understand that the presented sentence is a joke, which inspired me to respond with my own joke.

Comment: @Cord Yes, I get it!))

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The grammar/syntax is fine.

As for punctuation, I would be inclined to put a semicolon after "bed".  You might even consider an em-dash, to simulate the stand-up comedian's pregnant pause; however, the last half of your sentence is not really a punchline—the first half is!

Comment: Thanks a lot!! So, I should write this way... "As a rule, I don't take handsome dead conductors to bed; but if it is Bernstein, my husband doesn't mind". Sounds more witty?)

Comment: We hope so. With humor, it's hard to guess. In telling a joke aloud, it's all a matter of delivery—timing, intonation, emphasis, facial expression—written punctuation can only hint at some of these ;-)     .

Comment: Oh, and the pause might give the audience just time enough to wonder whether she usually takes _ugly, live_ conductors to bed!

Comment: Haha, you are very helpful! Thank you one more time)